# API integration - Need secure URL to POST notification data to

Tags: apex, api, integration

I am trying to integrate a program called Checkfront into our Salesforce. The primary goal is to have a new Account record created whenever a new object is created in checkfront. Checkfront is capable of directly POSTing details to an SSL-secured server endpoint. Notifications are sent over an HTTPS POST request in the form of a JSON or XML.

**Question:** What secure URL should I post my notification data to if I want want to access this data from Salesforce? See "notification URL" in image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to consider authentication here. If you create an open access URL (by e.g. using Force.com Sites) then anyone can inject data: you need to ensure that only requests from Checkfront are allowed. (Note someone else not me just downvoted your question as I was writing this.)

Comment: It is funny you mention this because I had just asked this Rob below. What is the method of ensuring that only a single source can post to the site? I have added a picture of my site in its current form. There is just a login and password field which I do not know the credentials to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a REST endpoint to which you can POST your Checkpoint data.

The article "[Creating REST APIs using Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)" will guide you through this, particularly the sections "Setting up an Apex REST endpoint" and "Using POST, PUT and PATCH":

> To declare a class as a custom endpoint, you only need to annotate a
>   global class with “@RestResource” and define the name of the endpoint.
>   In the above example, we start the class with the following lines:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/FieldCase/*')
global with sharing class RESTCaseController {
```

> **This will define “FieldCase” as an accessible endpoint and the full
>   URI would be constructed from your instance URL concatenated with
>   “/services/apexrest/FieldCase”. For example, something like
>   “https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/FieldCase”**.
>
> The POST HTTP method is mostly reserved for creating new records,
>   while PUT and PATCH can be utilized to modify and update existing
>   records. POST and similar methods submit a body of data, and Apex REST
>   has the ability to automatically decode that data into incoming
>   parameters on the function. So if an application sends the following
>   post data:

```
{“companyName”:”GenePoint”,”caseType”:”Software”}
```

> to the endpoint using the POST method, this example function above
>   will pick up those values automatically. So this code:

```
@HttpPost

  global static String createNewCase(String companyName, String caseType) {
     System.debug('COMPANY: '+companyName);
     System.debug('CASE TYPE: '+caseType);
     return “Done”;
   }
```

> would display “GenePoint” and “Software” correctly in the debug logs.

Comment: Thank you for the resources! I still need a URL to post the notifications to though, don't I? What do you recommend in terms of the URL?

Comment: Please see the section "Setting up an Apex REST endpoint" in the linked article.  I've updated my answer to include the relevant part in bold.

Comment: I may have to post another question for this, but maybe you can answer. Because I am using a Salesforce URL, will I need to authenticate the post from Checkfront in someway? Will checkfront have to login into our Salesforce in order to POST?

Comment: Glad this helped!  You would normally authenticate using [OAuth](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm).  Please go ahead and close this question and open another if you have any issues with the authentication process.